# event.preventDefault(); not stopping mousewheel in Firefox

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, preventdefault

I am using the mousewheel in jquery to increase the number of a div, the number increases correctly but the scroll is not stopped in Firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#test').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){

        var currentValue = parseInt($('#test').text(),10),
            newValue = currentValue + 1;

        $('#test').text(newValue);    
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rHVUn/

The fiddle uses the standard mousewheel detection, but I have also used Brandon Aaron's mousewheel plugin and it has the same problem.

Removing the line that updates the text (I have also tried html()) of the div resolves the issue, but this is a crucial part of the code and cannot be removed.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thank you

**Update:** I have found the problem only occurs when my mouse is positioned directly over the text, if my mouse is within the box but not over the text (within the padding) the scroll is stopped

Comment: I forgot to mention, if you scroll up a few times, then down the scroll is stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, it may not be the best way to do this but it works.

I found the problem only occurs when my mouse is positioned directly over the text during the scroll, so I added an overlaying element and use that as the mousewheel trigger.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rHVUn/9/
*(The background colour is not needed)*

Comment: An unfortunate hack; I am still suffering from the original issue :(

Answer (score 2):

This is still one of the top posts when I search for the issue of Firefox scrolling despite preventing the scroll event.

Firefox triggers two events on mouse scroll: `DOMMouseScroll` and `MozMousePixelScroll`. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/issues/45#issuecomment-11749359 It is necessary to prevent the `MozMousePixelScroll` event.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/MozMousePixelScroll the most modern event name is `wheel`, which appears to work with my version of Firefox (55) and Chrome (61). Probably this is what you should be using. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/WheelEvent

Here's a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ahpy9f66/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#test').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){

        var currentValue = parseInt($('#test').text(),10),
            newValue = currentValue + 1;

        $('#test').text(newValue);    
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I try using Brandon Aaron's mousewheel plugin it breaks again http://jsfiddle.net/rHVUn/6/, ideally I would like it to work with and without the plugin.

Comment: @Michael which firefox version are you using it is working correctly over my system ..!

Comment: I am using firefox version 15.0

Comment: @Michael me too..i hope you know for this code to work you have to keep your mouse inside #test div and then scroll..!

Comment: I do keep my mouse inside, at least I know it works for you, I will have to keep testing, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on chrome, firefox lattest versions and IE, [Try this](http://jsfidd):

```js
document.onmousewheel = function(){ stopWheel(); } /* IE7, IE8 */
if(document.addEventListener){ /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
    document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', stopWheel, false);
}
 
function stopWheel(e){
    if(!e){ e = window.event; } /* IE7, IE8, Chrome, Safari */
    if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */
    e.returnValue = false; /* IE7, IE8 */
}
```

```css
div {
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;;
    text-align:center;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
}
#test_ov {
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(45,65,40,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:900px; border:0;">
    <div id="test">0</div>
    <span id="test_ov"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers were working for me, but `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` worked.

Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63609840/10830621

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to bind 'mousewheel' event instead of what you have? :

```
$('#test').bind('mousewheel', function(event){ ...
```

I adapted your fiddle and it seems to work

Comment: Please can you post a link to the fiddle? I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: Firefox does not support `mousewheel`—instead use `DOMMouseScroll`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#objectId').on({
            'mousewheel': function(e) {                
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                }
            })
```

Use this instead, which works for me

Comment: This just plain does not work. The event still fires multiple times. So far as I've found, it's not possible to prevent the default behaviour of a mousewheel event. Still trying to figure out why to find a way to circumvent that problem.