# 'Wheel' events on touch screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, touch

I have this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/316n1xmL/1/ which works perfectly how I need it to on desktop. Counts up or down based on wheel scroll direction and adds and removes classes. The issue I am running into is how to do this on touch screens.

I have tried hammer.js but their documentation is really bad and not clear.

Sadly the site I am building is using bootstrap 4 which means I cannot use juqery mobile since BS4 uses jquery 3 which does not support jquery mobile.

Any help is appreciated

```js
// Scroll Direction Plugin Move Later to own file

!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=a:a(jQuery)}(function(a){function b(b){var g=b||window.event,h=i.call(arguments,1),j=0,l=0,m=0,n=0,o=0,p=0;if(b=a.event.fix(g),b.type="mousewheel","detail"in g&&(m=-1*g.detail),"wheelDelta"in g&&(m=g.wheelDelta),"wheelDeltaY"in g&&(m=g.wheelDeltaY),"wheelDeltaX"in g&&(l=-1*g.wheelDeltaX),"axis"in g&&g.axis===g.HORIZONTAL_AXIS&&(l=-1*m,m=0),j=0===m?l:m,"deltaY"in g&&(m=-1*g.deltaY,j=m),"deltaX"in g&&(l=g.deltaX,0===m&&(j=-1*l)),0!==m||0!==l){if(1===g.deltaMode){var q=a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height");j*=q,m*=q,l*=q}else if(2===g.deltaMode){var r=a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height");j*=r,m*=r,l*=r}if(n=Math.max(Math.abs(m),Math.abs(l)),(!f||f>n)&&(f=n,d(g,n)&&(f/=40)),d(g,n)&&(j/=40,l/=40,m/=40),j=Math[j>=1?"floor":"ceil"](j/f),l=Math[l>=1?"floor":"ceil"](l/f),m=Math[m>=1?"floor":"ceil"](m/f),k.settings.normalizeOffset&&this.getBoundingClientRect){var s=this.getBoundingClientRect();o=b.clientX-s.left,p=b.clientY-s.top}return b.deltaX=l,b.deltaY=m,b.deltaFactor=f,b.offsetX=o,b.offsetY=p,b.deltaMode=0,h.unshift(b,j,l,m),e&&clearTimeout(e),e=setTimeout(c,200),(a.event.dispatch||a.event.handle).apply(this,h)}}function c(){f=null}function d(a,b){return k.settings.adjustOldDeltas&&"mousewheel"===a.type&&b%120===0}var e,f,g=["wheel","mousewheel","DOMMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],h="onwheel"in document||document.documentMode>=9?["wheel"]:["mousewheel","DomMouseScroll","MozMousePixelScroll"],i=Array.prototype.slice;if(a.event.fixHooks)for(var j=g.length;j;)a.event.fixHooks[g[--j]]=a.event.mouseHooks;var k=a.event.special.mousewheel={version:"3.1.12",setup:function(){if(this.addEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.addEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=b;a.data(this,"mousewheel-line-height",k.getLineHeight(this)),a.data(this,"mousewheel-page-height",k.getPageHeight(this))},teardown:function(){if(this.removeEventListener)for(var c=h.length;c;)this.removeEventListener(h[--c],b,!1);else this.onmousewheel=null;a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-line-height"),a.removeData(this,"mousewheel-page-height")},getLineHeight:function(b){var c=a(b),d=c["offsetParent"in a.fn?"offsetParent":"parent"]();return d.length||(d=a("body")),parseInt(d.css("fontSize"),10)||parseInt(c.css("fontSize"),10)||16},getPageHeight:function(b){return a(b).height()},settings:{adjustOldDeltas:!0,normalizeOffset:!0}};a.fn.extend({mousewheel:function(a){return a?this.bind("mousewheel",a):this.trigger("mousewheel")},unmousewheel:function(a){return this.unbind("mousewheel",a)}})});

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var counter = 0;
    var scrollThreshold = 15;

    var tiles = $('.list-tile');

    $(window).on('wheel', function(event){
        // deltaY obviously records vertical scroll, deltaX and deltaZ exist too
        if(event.originalEvent.deltaY < 0){
          // wheeled up
          counter--;
            if (Math.abs(counter) >= scrollThreshold) {
                tiles.filter('.animate-up').not('.first').last().removeClass('animate-up');
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            // wheeled down
            counter++;
            if (counter >= scrollThreshold) {
                tiles.not('.animate-up').eq(0).addClass('animate-up');
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
      });

});
```

```css
.hero-list {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  touch-action: pan-x;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hero-list .hero-list-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 901;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
}
.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile .module-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transform: translate3d(0, -20%, 0) scale(1.5);
}
.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile.animate-up {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0) scale(1) !important;
}
.hero-list .hero-list-container .list-tile.animate-up .module-background {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0) scale(1) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero-list">
    <div class="hero-list-container">
     <div class="list-tile animate-up">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');
    background-size: cover;">

      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="list-tile">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');
    background-size: cover;">

      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="list-tile">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');
    background-size: cover;">

      </div>
     </div>

     <div class="list-tile">
      <div class="module-background" style="background-image: url('https://thomasstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/wp-media/2017/11/tech-background.png');
    background-size: cover;">

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to refactor a little bit Your plugin by detecting touch events. Hammer is a great library which can cover all the gesture types. If You need something lighter and straightforward, You can anyway add this functionality by yourself in plain JavaScript:

Add feature detection and touch handlers:

```
if("ontouchstart" in window){
   el.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStartHandler);
   el.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMoveHandler);
   el.addEventListener('touchend', touchEndHandler);
}
```

Put the code which is actually inside Your `onwheel` handler in its own function.

Now, You should decide what behavior You are about to implement in Your plugin: i.e. either if the scroll should happen during swipe down, or only after the finger has been released. Use that function inside the desired touch handler, either inside the `touchmove` or inside the `touchend` event.

As You need to use latest jQuery, I believe You don't need extra backward cross-browser compatibility, anyway here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27024624/4845566.

Lastly, You can add some more usability to Your plugin by allowing touch actions to be slightly diagonal, as by using the thumb is.  Here is a nice discussion about this topic with all the source code You need: [A simple swipe detection on vanilla js](https://gist.github.com/SleepWalker/da5636b1abcbaff48c4d)

Comment: Thanks so much! Yea I checked out hammer but their documentation I found lacking and it doesn't seem to have been updated super recently.